# Не запускается приложение на машине Win XP 32bit

Tags: c#, .net

В настройках выставлено принудительно net 4.0 и x86. На машине с вин10 все работает. На машине Win XP 32bit получаю ошибку

> Unable to find a version of the runtime to run this application.

При том, что другое мое приложение с такими же настройками написанное полтора года назад, работает нормально.

Comment: Наверное стоит добавит в вопрос версии установленных дотнетов

Comment: На машине установлены все фрэймворки, вплоть до 4. Версия приложения без указания x86,а с anycpu запускается нормально. Так что с версией net все нормально.

Comment: @corvered а вы пробовали поставить x86-версию фреймворка?

Comment: Я неправильно выразился. Версия как раз и указана х86 в настройках. С anycpu запускается старая версия, без кучи проделанных изменений.

Comment: Тоже часто сталкивался с и необьяснимыми .Net багами на xp и висте, несмотря на то, что. Net 4 был установлен. Как правило, решалось переустановкой . Net. Так же проверьте, чтобы ваша программа не использовала либы более поздних версий

Comment: Думаю просто нужно пересобрать для anycpu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пересобрал под anycpu и всё отлично